# CNN training loss is so unstable

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

[my CNN network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8kc9.png)

Above is my config of the network.
l am training a CNN network on picture size of 192*192.
my target is a classification network of 11 kinds.
However, the loss and the accuracy on testing dataset appears to be very unstable. l have to run 15+ epochs to get a stable accuracy and loss. The maximum accuracy is only 50%.
What can l do to improve the performance?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to first refer to models which are widely known like VGG-16, LeNET or VGG-19 and check out the way how the conv2D and max-pooling layers are placed.

Start with a very basic model without any batch normalization and Leaky ReLU layers. You just keep the conv2D and max pooling layers and train your model for a few epochs.

Next, try other activations like ReLU to TanH. Try Changing the max pooling to average pooling.

If you are solving a classification problem then use the softmax layer at the end. Also, introduce Dense layer(s) after flattening.

Your dataset should be large and also the target should be one-hot encoded if you wish to use the softmax layer.